# Cross Product In HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql

While Running hive query on map reduce my job is stuck at a particular stage.I don't have any idea why it's running very slow.

I can't put the whole query but will post just part of it.I have already table called TICKET_V and TICKET_R. Now my query is following...

`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE TICKET_V
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TICKET_R AS B ON A.TICKET_NO= B.TICKET_NO
LEFT OUTER JOIN TICKET_X AS C ON A.COMPANY_ID = C.COMPANY_ID
WHERE SOME CONDITION`

Here TICKET_R, CUSTOMER, TICKET_X Table have respectively 55M,20M,2M Rows.Everything runs smoothly and got a TICKET_V table with 0.8M rows.

Now I run another query following which depends on TICKET_V which is following...

`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE TICKET_R
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER_R AS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN TICKET_R AS D ON C.TICKET_NO = D.TICKET_NO
WHERE SOME CONDITION`

CUSTOMER_R has around 2M rows.

After running this query on hive console Firstly I got a warning as follows:
`Warning: Map Join MAPJOIN[57][bigTable=?] in task 'stage-14: MAPRED' is a cross product
 Warning: Shuffle Join JOIN[31][table=[table alias names]] in stage 'Stage-2: MAPRED' is a cross product`

I don't understand why hive is doing a cross product on the second query while I had given a condition while everything runs well on the first query even data size is more.

If somebody gives me more light on the query then it would be helpful.I am very new to map reduce and Yes this problem is from my work.

Edits are welcome...!!
Thanks.

Comment: i would suggest run explain formatted yourquery and update the question